# Marathon event subscriptions

Tags: mesos, marathon

have been trying to enable event subscriptions. I found the Marathon REST API. I attempted to restart marathon with the `"--event_subscriber http_callback"` and created the `"event_subscriber"` and `"http_endpoints"`. When i restart it shows `" --http_endpoints http://localhost:1234/"` and I am running `"nc -l -p 1234"` to listen to the port. I am not getting anything when i create new apps.

It seems that i am having trouble enabling it. As i keep getting the error.

```
"http event callback system is not running on this Marathon instance. Please re-start this instance with \"--event_subscriber http_callback\"
```

Maybe i am missing something? Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue resolved! i fixed it by running the following command

```
 marathon --jar --master zk://your_ip:5050,your_ip:5050,your_ip:5050/mesos --event_subscriber http_callback
```

and to get it to take restart marathon on ALL masters

```
sudo service marathon restart
```

Once back up check the page and you should be good to go.